# How to use debugger in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator for C++ projects (non-Qt actually). This might be a dumb question, but how do you manage to use the debugger in `Qt Creator`? I have been using `CDB` along with VisualStudio or `gdb` along with IDEs like `Code::Blocks` and they are all intuitive to use. When it comes to `Qt Creator` though, I'm hopeless!

For instance, I've tried putting breakpoints, but when I run the code, it just skips the breakpoints without doing anything! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should make "Debug" target, not "Release" one (located projects tab -> build settings -> build configuration)
- You should use Debug menu items "Start debugging", "Step over", "Continue" etc, not just "Run"

hope it helps.