# How to trace the source code in QT?

Tags: qt

I want to trace the source code , but when I set a breakpoint, the program doesn't pause. 
How can I do that and are there some settings I should set?

My environment is Qt SDK.

[image]

Comment: Please give more information on your environment: are you on windows or linux or OSX? Are you using MinGW or MSVC (on windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we've confirmed that your GDB is working properly, the problem is that in order to be able to debug Qt code, the Qt code needs to be compiled in debug mode.

Be warned though, it will take a lot of time to compile Qt in debug mode.

Comment: Google it. Also, the standard term for "tracing the source code" is "interactive debugging". @GradGuy's answer should solve your problem.

Comment: The screenshot is completely useless.

Comment: Did you follow GradGuy's instructions and the instructions of the question he linked to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9270/discussion-between-jordoex-and-tu-jianwu)

Answer (score 2):

You should compile under `Debug` mode and hit `start debugging` instead of normal run. I use to have the same exact problem. Here, this might help: [How to use debugger in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730072/how-to-use-debugger-in-qt-creator)

Comment: firstly thanks for your help,, the source code 's not mine, is QT , is it the same?

Comment: Yes, the as long as you can see the source code, the debugger will run.

Comment: @Tu_JianWu Yes. Qt Creator uses `GDB` on linux and Windows by default (although it can be configured to work with `CDB` on windows if you wanted to). As such, any valid c++ code, including all of Qt Framework, can be "debugged" using the debugger.

Comment: i have update it with a picture,, it doesn't pause on break point..where is the fault ?